# I have to check if an element of the array is the same as the previous one (java)

Tags: java

I followed the advice of the site but I did not find answers that satisfied me.
I have to solve a school exercise. I have an array and I need to check if there is at least a sequence of 3 consecutive "a" characters.

```
public static String alternative(char[] a) {
    String ret = "";
    int consecutiveCounter = 0;
    int i = 1;
     while(consecutiveCounter<3){
         while(i<= a.length){
             if(a[i] =='a' && a[i] == a[i-1] ) {

                consecutiveCounter++;
            } else {
                consecutiveCounter = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (consecutiveCounter == 3) {
        ret += "there are three consecutive a char";
    } else {
        ret += "there are not three consecutive a char";
    }
    return ret;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] a = new char[]{'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'};
    System.out.println(alternative(a));

}
```

the terminal gives me this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7
at Es1.alternative(Es1.java:9)
at Es1.main(Es1.java:31)

I can't increase the value of the index (i) without going out of the array bounds

Comment: Then... don't run out of bounds?

Comment: since index starts from 0, `i` cant be same as array lenght. so `i<a.length()`

Comment: *"I followed the advice of the site but I did not find answers that satisfied me."* - Then you need to take a different approach.  Rather than looking for "advice" (on how to solve the problem), try to actually understand what the problem really is.  Understand what >your< code does and why you are getting an exception.  Then figure out what mistake >you< have made, and how to correct the mistake.  Basically ... learn how to **debug** your code.

Comment: Here are a couple of links to help you develop your debugging skills:  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Comment: (Or ... you could just console yourself by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrIPxlFzDi0) :-) )

Comment: Stephen C English is not my first language and I apologize if I have caused any misunderstandings.

the text of my question was intended to explain that, given the advice of the site (stackoverflow), I had looked for questions similar to mine, but I had not found them.

Comment: I know I don't have great IT skills but I'm just starting out. thanks for scolding me, it will serve as a lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to use `for` loops here, both checking the bounds of array, and the inner counting occurrences of `'a'` and returning early as soon as the required limit is reached:

```java
public static String alternative(char[] a) {
    for (int i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ) {
        for (int count = 1; i < n && a[i++] == 'a'; count++) {
            if (count == 3) {
                return "there are three consecutive 'a' chars";
            }
        }
    }
    return "there are not three consecutive 'a' chars";
}
```

It's worth mentioning that `String` class (which is basically built on char array) has several methods to implement this functionality:

- `String::contains`: `"aabbccaaa".contains("aaa") // true`
- `String::indexOf`: `"aabbccaa".indexOf("aaa") // -1, aaa not found`
- `String::matches` (using regular expression): `"aabbaaaccaa".matches(".*a{3}.*") // true`

Answer (score 0):

Also, I don't think your outer looping will work well.
1.Suppose there is no consecutive char, then `consecutiveCounter` will remain `0` and `while(consecutiveCounter<3)` wont end.
2.Even if there is one or two, but it will be set to `0` again, and `while(consecutiveCounter<3)` wont end.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

- Use a for loop from `i = 1 to i < a.length`.  Then `i` won't exceed the last index of the array.
- You are only trying to find 3 consecutive `'a's`.  So initialize `consecutiveCounter` to 1.
- As soon as the first consecutive pair are found, you increment `consecutiveCounter` and it will now be 2 which is correct.
- Then in the same `if clause` check to see if that value equals 3.  If so, return the String immediately (you may have even 4 or 5 consecutive `a's` but you also have 3 so return when the count of 3 is first encountered.
- Else, if the if statement fails, reset `consecutiveCounter` to 1 and continue the loop.
- At the end, outside the loop, return the string that indicates the requirement wasn't met.

Note:  If you were trying to find the maximum number of consecutive `a's` setting the counter to `1` wouldn't work because you may have no `a's` at all.  But since you are looking for a specific number == 3, it works fine.